# TSQL multiple values in where clause using XML nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, nodes

I have the code below. I've used something very similar to this before to allow the input of multiple values in a comma delimited string.

For some reason though the query only takes the very first value and doesn't continue reading in values. `@Tables` would be something like `"Table1, table2, table3"` Can someone see my mistake? It works with numbers if I do `'1, 2, 3, 4'` on a database it works but it doesn't work with strings.

```
DECLARE @TableXML AS XML
SET @TableXML = cast(('<a>'+replace(@Tables,',' ,'</a><a>')
             +'</a>') AS XML);

SELECT
*   
FROM CABDetail 
WHERE CABDetail.BudgetName in (SELECT
    a.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    FROM @TableXML.nodes('a') AS FN(a)
)

ORDER BY CABDetail.account
```

Comment: Should've worked assuming `CABDetail.BudgetName` contains one of the values Table1, table2, table3. Can you create sample table with data that can be used to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could `TRIM` result: `Table1, table2, table3`:

```
SELECT *   
FROM CABDetail 
WHERE CABDetail.BudgetName in (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(a.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))
                               FROM @TableXML.nodes('a') AS FN(a)
)
ORDER BY CABDetail.account;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483824)**</kbd>

Reason is very simple, when you parse you will get:

```
'Table1'
' table2'
' table3'
```

and when comparing  `'table2'` is different than `' table2'`.

It works with numbers, because you could implicitly `CAST` `' 2'` to integer.

```
SELECT CAST(' 2' AS INT);
-- 2
```

Another possibility replacing `', '` instead of  `','`:

```
DECLARE @TableXML AS XML
SET @TableXML = cast(('<a>'+replace(@Tables,', ' ,'</a><a>')
      +'</a>') AS XML);
```

---

From `SQL Server 2016+` you could use built-in `STRING_SPLIT` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM #CABDetail
WHERE BudgetName in (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM([value]))
                     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Tables, ','));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483827)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL script seems to be working successfully on my SQL2014 db

```
declare @Tables as nvarchar(max) = 'Table1, table2, table3'

DECLARE @TableXML AS XML
SET @TableXML = cast(('<a>'+replace(@Tables,',' ,'</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML);

SELECT
a.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
FROM @TableXML.nodes('a') AS FN(a)
```

There seems nothing to be a problem
But you can think of using a [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) and use it in the Select statement as follows as an alternative if you can not identify the problem in your case

```
declare @Tables as nvarchar(max) = 'Table1, table2, table3'
SELECT val FROM dbo.Split(@Tables, ',') a
```